# Сдвиг пальцем ячейки UITableViewCell на фиксированное расстояние

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, swipe

Необходимо, чтобы при попытке сдвинуть ячейку таблицы пальцем вправо, она смещалась на небольшое фиксированное расстояние, а при отпускании - возвращалась на место.

Как при этом отлавливать данное действие (при возвращении положения ячейки), чтобы к примеру менять картинку слева от названия?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте на ячейку ещё один слой UIView, и на него поместите все свои контролы. Так же добавьте на ячейку UIPanGestureRecognizer, он будет отлавливать движения пальца (можете сделать свой recognizer чтобы отменять распознавание при движении пальца вниз). Не забудьте назначить для recognizer делегата, так как у scrollView есть свой recognizer и поэтому для вашего нужно вурнуть YES в методе

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer * _Nonnull)gestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer * _Nonnull)otherGestureRecognizer
```

При сдвиге, просто меняйте положение добавленной UIView, а при отпускании с анимацией возвращайте UIView на место методом

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                 animations:(void (^ _Nonnull)(void))animations
                 completion:(void (^ _Nullable)(BOOL finished))completion
```

При этом в блоке completion можете делать необходимые вам изменения.